# How to feed Keras model with multiple inputs through fit_generator

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to solve a machine learning problem which accepts both an image input as well as a text input, for which I am simply vectorizing using a bag-of-words model.

I've used the function below to set up two generators to the model. This was largely based off simonst's answer in [In keras, how to fit multiple input data with different type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48017731/in-keras-how-to-fit-multiple-input-data-with-different-type), which was really helpful.

```
def create_generators(x_train_feat, x_val_feat, train_batch_size, val_batch_size):

    '''
    Training function
    '''

    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        featurewise_center=False,
        samplewise_center=False,
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,
        samplewise_std_normalization=False,
        zca_whitening=False,
        zca_epsilon=0,
        rotation_range=0.05,
        width_shift_range=0.05,
        height_shift_range=0.05,
        channel_shift_range=0,
        fill_mode='nearest',
        cval=0,
        vertical_flip=False,
        rescale=1./255,
        shear_range=0.,
        zoom_range=0.,
        horizontal_flip=False)


    val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rescale=1./255,
        featurewise_std_normalization=False,
        featurewise_center=False)


    train_generator=train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=subset_df_train,
        directory='./',
        x_col="image_path",
        y_col="Category_Name",
        batch_size=train_batch_size,
        seed=42,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode="categorical",
        target_size=target_size)

    validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
        dataframe=subset_df_valid,
        directory="./",
        x_col="image_path",
        y_col="Category_Name",
        batch_size=val_batch_size,
        seed=42,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode="categorical",
        target_size=target_size)

    def train_feat_gen(x_train_feat, train_batch_size):
        while True:
            for batch in range(len(x_train_feat) // train_batch_size + 1):
                if batch > max(range(len(x_train_feat) // train_batch_size)):
                    yield x_train_feat[batch*train_batch_size:]
                else:
                    yield x_train_feat[batch*train_batch_size:(1+batch)*train_batch_size]

    def val_feat_gen(x_val_feat, val_batch_size):
        while True:
            for batch in range(len(x_val_feat) // val_batch_size + 1):
                if batch > max(range(len(x_val_feat) // val_batch_size)):
                    yield x_val_feat[batch*val_batch_size:]
                else:
                    yield x_val_feat[batch*val_batch_size:(1+batch)*val_batch_size]

    def merge_generator(gen1, gen2):
        while True:
            X1 = gen1.__next__()
            X2 = gen2.__next__()
            yield [X1[0], X2], X1[1]



    final_train_gen = merge_generator(train_generator, train_feat_gen(x_train_feat, train_batch_size))
    final_val_gen = merge_generator(validation_generator, val_feat_gen(x_val_feat, val_batch_size))


    return (final_train_gen,final_val_gen)

final_train_gen,final_val_gen = create_generators(aux_train, aux_valid, 16, 16)
```

Unfortunately when I then run the model with the below code,

```
hist = model.fit_generator(
    final_train_gen,
    steps_per_epoch=train_len // 16,
    epochs=3,
    validation_data=final_val_gen,
    validation_steps=valid_len // 16)
```

I encounter the following error: ValueError: All input arrays (x) should have the same number of samples. Got array shapes: [(16, 128, 128, 3), (0, 2160)].

This only occurs on the 2nd epoch, however. The first one trains okay. Based on the (0,2160), it looks like the 2nd epoch is not loading the batches (my batch size is 16) properly. Unfortunately, as I don't have a strong grasp of how the above create_generators function works to merge the two, I'm not very sure where the problem lies, and would greatly appreciate help/guidance on this.

Apologies as the code is experimental and hence a little messy and some of the underlying context is missing - I hope I've included information enough to understand the issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a single generator to pair up each image with its associated text. Simply pass the data frame or file for both the images and texts to your fit_generator function, and process them such that they match based on the criteria you have (e.g. an ID), and yield arrays that have a certain size, matching your desired batch size. Then, you can yield a tuple like in your code, but now you can guarantee that the batch sizes match.
If you really want to use two generators, you can have a look here:
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/8130